# Move file to another directory in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, java, performance, jmeter

I'm trying to do performance test in Jmeter so before run my test i have to get fresh data, basically I need to move my used csv file after completed test execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(new File('/current/path/to/csv.file'),new File('/new/path/to/csv.file'))
   ```
4. That's it, the setUp Thread Group is executed before "main" Thread Groups and the code will move the file

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You will have to run the command specific to your operating system (Windows, Mac , Linux)

You can use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to move the CSV file to a different location.

> The OS Process Sampler is a sampler that can be used to execute commands on the local machine.
> It should allow execution of any command that can be run from the command line.
> Validation of the return code can be enabled, and the expected return code can be specified.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 2**

You can use Groovy to perform the command.
Add a JSR223 Sampler with following script

On Mac/Linux

```
"mv pathToSrcFile targetFolder".execute()
SampleResult.setIgnore()
```

On Windows

```
"move pathToSrcFile targetFolder".execute()
SampleResult.setIgnore()
```